# {Errno 2} No such file or directory (in Google Collab)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, google-colaboratory

I need to test a model (on Google Collab) by feeding the network , all the .png files present in location **"/content/DataSet/Test Images"**

For this, I need to:

- Access each image in the folder
- resize them
- Convert them into a numPy array

This is what I tried:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(test_img_dir):
      if filename.endswith(".png"):
        im = image.imread(filename)
        #Followed By Resizing and conversion into NumPy array
```

But this is what I get:

```
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lg566 (400).png'
```

I can verify that the image is indeed present. Why is this happening and how should I go through?

I have added a notebook that reproduces the problem [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1198tG2EUw-GyePuUlhZFGOCN0GzGUkzg)

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem. The important part will be observing how and where you transfer the directory DataSet to the backend.

Comment: @BobSmith I have done it. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `os.listdir()` will give you a list of the files within the directory you are using, without the relative path to them. That leaves you with several options.

Option A:

Prepend the path to the file, that is:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if filename.endswith(".png"):
    im = image.imread(path+"/"+filename)
    ...
```

Option B: glob

```
from glob import glob

for filename in glob(path+"/*.png"):
  im = image.imread(filename)
  ...
```